# Finding the positive root of $x^3 +x^2 =0.1$ by numerical methods.

Tags: numerical-methods, roots

The positive root of $x^3 +x^2 =0.1$ is denoted to be $A$.

$(a)$ Find the first approximation to $A$ by linear interpolation on the interval $(0,1)$

For this, I got $x_1 =0.05$

$(b)$ Indicate why linear interpolation does not give a good approximation to $A$.

All I think of for this is that $x_1$ by linear interpolation greatly underestimates $A$ to a large extent. But wouldn't numerical methods like Newton-Raphson, Linear Interpolation and iteration $x_{n+1}=F(x_n)$ all give bad first approximations?

$(c)$ Find an alternative first approximation to $A$ by using the fact that if $x$ is small then $x^3$ is negligible compared with $x^2$

So, for this am I supposed to use Newton-Raphson with $x_1=0$ since $x$ is small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) Correct. (b) Yes. It is also bad because $1$ is far away from the root, as can be seen comparing the function values. And the function is very non-linear around $x=0$, making linear approximations relatively bad.
[image]

(c) No, you are supposed to solve $x^2=0.1$, disregarding the $x^3$ term. Or to put it into inequalities, as $0<x<1$ you also have
$$
x^2\le 0.1\le 2x^2\implies \sqrt{0.05}\le x \le \sqrt{0.1}.
$$
Then iterate further, for instance using $x_{k+1}=\sqrt{\frac{0.1}{1+x_k}}$.

```
k    x[k]
------------------
1   0.316227766017
2   0.275635071544
3   0.279986295554
4   0.279509993492
5   0.279562012937
6   0.279556330208
7   0.279556950986
8   0.279556883172
9   0.27955689058
```

Comment: So, I have 2 qn. 
1) How do you get from $0<x<1$ to $x^2\le 0.1\le 2x^2$ ?
2) Why use $x_{k+1}=\sqrt{\frac{0.1}{1+x_k}}$ ? Is $x_{k+1}=(0.1-(x_k)^2)^{1/3}$ okay?

Comment: 1) Put $x^2+x^3$ in place of $0.1$

Comment: $0<x<1\implies 0<x^3<x^2\implies x^2<0.1<2x^2$. If computing with positive quantities it makes life more predictable if all intermediate terms stay positive. Some iteration formulas will be divergent. Computing using the secant or Dekker's method will be faster than such simple iterations.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the tips!

Answer (score 0):

*Just for your curiosity.*

We can approximate functions using [Padé approximants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant) much better than with Taylor series (remember that Newton method is equivalent to an $O(x^2)$ Taylor expansion).

Since we know how to solve easily quadratic equations, let us consider the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant. It will be
$$x^3+x^2 \sim\frac{x^2}{x^2-x+1}$$ If you develop the rhs of the above as a Taylor series, you would get $x^2+x^3-x^5+O\left(x^6\right)$ (pretty close, isn't it ?).

So, for small values of $a$, the *approximate* solution of $x^3+x^2=a$ is given by the solution of $(1-a) x^2+a x-a=0$ that is to say
$$x_\pm=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{4 a-3 a^2}}{2 (a-1)}$$ So, for $a=\frac 1 {10}$, the estimate would be $x\approx 0.282376$ which is quite close to the "exact" solution   $x\approx 0.279557$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

- Start with the iteration
  $$
  x_{n} = \root{0.1 - x_{n}^{3}}\,,\qquad
  x_{0} = \root{0.1} \approx 0.3162
  $$
  It seems to be that $\ds{10}$ iterations are enough. Namely, $$
  x_{10} \approx 0.279564\quad\mbox{and}\quad\mrm{f}\pars{x_{10}} \approx 5.43129 \times 10^{-6} 
  $$
  where $\bbox[10px,#ffd,border: 1px groove navy]{\ds{\mrm{f}\pars{x} \equiv x^{3} + x^{2} - 0.1}}$.
- In addition, you can *refine* the above result by means of a *Newton-Rapson* Iteration:
  $$
  y_{n} = y_{n - 1} - {y_{n - 1}^{3} + y_{n - 1}^{2} - 0.1 \over
  3y_{n - 1}^{2} + 2y_{n - 1}}\,,\qquad y_{0} = x_{10} \approx 0.279564
  $$
  With about three iterations, I'll find
  $$
  y_{3} \approx \bbx{\large 0.279957} \implies \mrm{f}\pars{y_{3}} \approx
  2.77556 \times10^{-17}
  $$ 
  \begin{align}
  \end{align}